# "insufficient free space" error when trying to create new logical volume?

Tags: partitioning, lvm

I have a dedicated server using LVM. I'm following a guide in the Ubuntu docs which says:

> sudo lvcreate -L 10G -n lv_vm_ubuntu /dev/[VGNAME]

Since my logical volume group name is `0`, I tried to create a new logical volume using:

```
sudo lvcreate -L 20G -n lv_vm_ubuntu /dev/0
```

But the following error was output:

```
Volume group "0" has insufficient free space (0 extents): 5120 required.
```

Here's information on my disks:

```
sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
```

Output:

```
NAME              FSTYPE              SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda                                 223.6G            
└─sda1            LVM2_member       223.6G            
  ├─0-swap (dm-0) swap                7.5G [SWAP]     
  └─0-root (dm-1) ext4              216.1G /          
sdb                                 931.5G            
└─sdb1            linux_raid_member 931.5G            ubuntu:0
  └─md0           ext4              931.4G /mnt/md0   
sdc                                 931.5G            
└─sdc1            linux_raid_member 931.5G            ubuntu:0
  └─md0           ext4              931.4G /mnt/md0
```

```
cat /etc/fstab
```

Output

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/0-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /mnt/md0 was on /dev/md0 during installation
UUID=bc5a499c-af64-467c-b9af-bc84af26e23c /mnt/md0        ext4    defaults        0       2
/dev/mapper/0-swap none            swap    sw              0       0
```

```
vgs
```

Output:

```
  VG   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  0      1   2   0 wz--n- 223.57g    0
```

```
vgdisplay
```

Output:

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               0
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  3
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               223.57 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              57233
  Alloc PE / Size       57233 / 223.57 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               RC1AXq-ev6F-ll0T-6COG-9yPU-OaSV-hjeSKB
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

UPDATE:

```
lvs
```

Output:

```
LV   VG   Attr      LSize   Pool Origin Data%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
root 0    -wi-ao--- 216.12g                                           
swap 0    -wi-ao---   7.45g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already had allocated all PE in VG 0  to the logical volume.

Do `lvs` to find which LV that associated to the VG 0 and find the LV size to compared.

Comment: Updated my question with the output of `lvs`. So are you saying I need to shrink the `root` logical volume so that I can create the new logical volume under the `0` volume group? Thanks for your help, this is my first time working with LVs.

Comment: Correct but shrinking rootfs is not something direct. Guide are massively avail from the net. Or if you have free partition or hdd, you can add into the VG for space extension. If this is satisfied, appreciate if you could mark this answered.

Comment: Hmm.. So it looks like the partition can't be resized while the volume is mounted, so is it even possible to resize it since it's on a server I don't have physical access to? Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, if you have remote console. Other than that sorry.